# Getting multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback error on multiprocessing.pool.starmap() method

Tags: python

I'm trying to develop a code that gets certain data from an API and constructs an output file using said data. In order to accelerate the processing time, I'm (attempting to) make use of the multiprocessing library to paralellize this task.

With the code below, I manage to get some results returned, but at seemingly random times (after 2-4 results have been received) I get the following error:

> multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x000002CA8BA44BD0>'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <function HTTPResponse.getheaders at 0x000002CA8BA06980>: it's not the same object as http.client.HTTPResponse.getheaders")'

Here's the code:

```
def function1 (origin: str, departureDate: datetime, returnDate: datetime):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        destinations = ["PAR", "LON", "AMS", "ROM", "BER", "BRU", "MUC"]

        res = []

        with Pool() as pool:
            pool.starmap(function2, zip(list(repeat(origin,7)), args, list(repeat(departureDate, 7)), 
list(repeat(returnDate, 7))))

        x = [r[0] for r in res]

        with open("res.json", "w") as outfile:
            json.dump(x, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

function1("MAD", datetime.datetime(2023,3,1), datetime.datetime(2023,3,8))
```

```
def function2 (origin: str, destination: str, departureDate: datetime, returnDate: datetime):

    vuelo = v.function3(origin, destination, departureDate, returnDate)
    habitacion = h.function4(destino, departureDate, returnDate)
    
    if(len(habitacion)!=0): habitacion = habitacion[0][0]

    result = {
        "destination": destination,
        "totalPrice": (float(room["offers"][0]["price"]["total"]) + 
float(flight["price"]["total"])),
        "hotelPrice": float(room["offers"][0]["price"]["total"])/2,
        "departurePrice": float(flight["price"]["departure"]),
        "returnPrice": float(flight["price"]["return"])
    
    print(result) #this is to test the output
    return result
```

```
def function3 (origin: str, destination: str, departureDate: datetime, returnDate: datetime):
    data = {#request parameters}

    try:
        response = provider.post(data)
        
        return response.data

    except ResponseError as error:
        raise error
```

```
def function4 (destination: str, departureDate: datetime, returnDate: datetime):
    #if __name__ == '__main__':
        hotels = GetHotels(destination)

        res = []

        for hotel in hotels:
            res.append(function5 (hotel,departureDate,returnDate))

        rooms = list(filter(None, res[0]))
        
        return rooms
```

```
def function5 (hotels, departureDate: datetime, returnDate: datetime):
    roomList = []

    try:
        hotel_offers = provider.get(#params)
        
        if(hotel_offers.data != []): 
            roomList.append(hotel_offers.data)

    except Exception: 0

    if roomList == []: roomList.append("")

    return roomList
```

Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\folder\folder\user\function2.py", line 49, in <module>
    function1("MAD", datetime.datetime(2023,3,1), datetime.datetime(2023,3,8))
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\folder\folder\user\function2.py", line 42, in function1
    pool.starmap(function2, zip(list(repeat(origin,7)), args, list(repeat(departureDate, 7)), list(repeat(returnDate, 7))))
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 375, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '<multiprocessing.pool.ExceptionWithTraceback object at 0x00000246DDDA4C50>'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <function HTTPResponse.getheaders at 0x00000246DDD66980>: it's not the same object as http.client.HTTPResponse.getheaders")'
```

I have tried using different approaches to paralellize my code, even rewritting functions 3, 4 and 5 as they're the ones that deal with network data fetching, but to no avail, and I can't find the cause for this error.

Comment: Are you using a notebook (like Jupyter) ?

Comment: The code you provide is far from a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) : missing imports, invalid syntax, missing variable definitions, ... I can't reproduce your problem with the code you posted, it won't run at all.